# SVG background blur is not showing in browser

Tags: html, css, svg, blur

I'm using an svg for my modal window, but he element containing the background blur is not displaying. Is there a way to fix this?

Here is my svg code:

```html
<svg width="64" height="58" viewBox="0 0 64 58" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <g filter="url(#filter0_b_2218_32457)">
    <circle cx="27.0196" cy="28.6371" r="26.7696" fill="url(#paint0_linear_2218_32457)"/>
  </g>
  <g filter="url(#filter1_b_2218_32457)">
    <circle cx="35.1128" cy="28.6373" r="28.6373" fill="#B9DDFF" fill-opacity="0.6"/>
    <circle cx="35.1128" cy="28.6373" r="28.4468" stroke="url(#paint1_linear_2218_32457)" stroke-width="0.380935"/>
  </g>
  <path d="M33.7771 44.8765H33.7016C32.3932 44.8074 31.1427 44.3146 30.1389 43.4725L23.1946 37.8114C22.4746 37.2229 21.8949 36.4811 21.498 35.6402C21.101 34.7992 20.8967 33.8803 20.8999 32.9504V21.8546C20.8995 20.6537 21.2435 19.4779 21.891 18.4665C22.5385 17.4551 23.4624 16.6505 24.5532 16.1482L31.4975 12.978C32.3156 12.5973 33.2069 12.4 34.1092 12.4C35.0115 12.4 35.9028 12.5973 36.7209 12.978L43.65 16.1482C44.7437 16.6483 45.6707 17.4519 46.321 18.4635C46.9713 19.4751 47.3175 20.6521 47.3184 21.8546V25.8099C47.3184 26.1101 47.1992 26.3981 46.9868 26.6105C46.7745 26.8228 46.4865 26.9421 46.1862 26.9421C45.8859 26.9421 45.598 26.8228 45.3856 26.6105C45.1733 26.3981 45.054 26.1101 45.054 25.8099V21.8546C45.0529 21.0859 44.8321 20.3336 44.4175 19.6863C44.0029 19.039 43.4119 18.5238 42.7141 18.2013L35.7698 15.0462C35.2462 14.8071 34.6773 14.6833 34.1016 14.6833C33.526 14.6833 32.9571 14.8071 32.4335 15.0462L25.5043 18.2013C24.8065 18.5238 24.2155 19.039 23.8009 19.6863C23.3863 20.3336 23.1655 21.0859 23.1644 21.8546V32.9504C23.1675 33.5486 23.3047 34.1386 23.566 34.6768C23.8272 35.215 24.2059 35.6877 24.674 36.0602L31.6183 41.7213C32.2661 42.2519 33.0626 42.5684 33.8978 42.6271C34.1736 42.6671 34.4249 42.8074 34.6037 43.0212C34.7825 43.2349 34.8762 43.5071 34.8668 43.7856C34.8575 44.0641 34.7458 44.3293 34.5531 44.5306C34.3603 44.7319 34.1002 44.855 33.8224 44.8765H33.7771ZM48.2544 35.1394C48.2514 33.6292 47.8009 32.1538 46.9597 30.8996C46.1186 29.6454 44.9245 28.6687 43.5285 28.0929C42.1324 27.517 40.597 27.3679 39.1162 27.6644C37.6355 27.9608 36.2758 28.6895 35.209 29.7584C34.1422 30.8273 33.4162 32.1884 33.1227 33.6698C32.8291 35.1511 32.9813 36.6862 33.5599 38.0811C34.1385 39.4761 35.1176 40.6682 36.3734 41.5069C37.6293 42.3455 39.1055 42.7932 40.6157 42.7932C42.643 42.7892 44.5859 41.981 46.018 40.5461C47.4501 39.1112 48.2544 37.1667 48.2544 35.1394ZM45.99 35.1394C45.99 36.2023 45.6748 37.2414 45.0842 38.1251C44.4937 39.0089 43.6544 39.6978 42.6723 40.1045C41.6903 40.5113 40.6097 40.6177 39.5672 40.4104C38.5247 40.203 37.5671 39.6912 36.8155 38.9395C36.0639 38.1879 35.552 37.2303 35.3447 36.1878C35.1373 35.1453 35.2437 34.0647 35.6505 33.0827C36.0573 32.1007 36.7461 31.2613 37.6299 30.6708C38.5137 30.0803 39.5528 29.7651 40.6157 29.7651C42.041 29.7651 43.408 30.3313 44.4159 31.3392C45.4238 32.347 45.99 33.714 45.99 35.1394ZM47.8468 40.9212C47.5482 40.9212 47.2564 41.0098 47.0081 41.1757C46.7599 41.3415 46.5664 41.5773 46.4521 41.8532C46.3378 42.129 46.3079 42.4325 46.3662 42.7254C46.4244 43.0182 46.5682 43.2872 46.7793 43.4983C46.9905 43.7095 47.2595 43.8532 47.5523 43.9115C47.8451 43.9697 48.1487 43.9398 48.4245 43.8256C48.7004 43.7113 48.9361 43.5178 49.102 43.2696C49.2679 43.0213 49.3564 42.7294 49.3564 42.4309C49.3564 42.0305 49.1974 41.6465 48.9143 41.3634C48.6312 41.0803 48.2472 40.9212 47.8468 40.9212Z" fill="url(#paint2_linear_2218_32457)" fill-opacity="0.9"/>
  <defs>
    <filter id="filter0_b_2218_32457" x="-7.87846" y="-6.26097" width="69.7962" height="69.7962" filterUnits="userSpaceOnUse" color-interpolation-filters="sRGB">
      <feFlood flood-opacity="0" result="BackgroundImageFix"/>
      <feGaussianBlur in="BackgroundImageFix" stdDeviation="4.06423"/>
      <feComposite in2="SourceAlpha" operator="in" result="effect1_backgroundBlur_2218_32457"/>
      <feBlend mode="normal" in="SourceGraphic" in2="effect1_backgroundBlur_2218_32457" result="shape"/>
    </filter>
    <filter id="filter1_b_2218_32457" x="-1.65287" y="-8.12846" width="73.5313" height="73.5315" filterUnits="userSpaceOnUse" color-interpolation-filters="sRGB">
      <feFlood flood-opacity="0" result="BackgroundImageFix"/>
      <feGaussianBlur in="BackgroundImageFix" stdDeviation="4.06423"/>
      <feComposite in2="SourceAlpha" operator="in" result="effect1_backgroundBlur_2218_32457"/>
      <feBlend mode="normal" in="SourceGraphic" in2="effect1_backgroundBlur_2218_32457" result="shape"/>
    </filter>
    <linearGradient id="paint0_linear_2218_32457" x1="15.694" y1="13.5792" x2="56.7742" y2="27.7063" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
      <stop stop-color="#7FC0FB"/>
      <stop offset="1" stop-color="#4088F4"/>
    </linearGradient>
    <linearGradient id="paint1_linear_2218_32457" x1="2.38455" y1="5.20677" x2="83.318" y2="46.9948" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
      <stop stop-color="white"/>
      <stop offset="1" stop-color="white" stop-opacity="0"/>
    </linearGradient>
    <linearGradient id="paint2_linear_2218_32457" x1="20.8086" y1="28.525" x2="60.9395" y2="37.833" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
      <stop stop-color="white"/>
      <stop offset="1" stop-color="white" stop-opacity="0"/>
    </linearGradient>
  </defs>
</svg>
```

Comment: Seems OK to me, although an feFlood with a flood-opacity of 0 seems kind of pointless.